# Recently got access to the Amazon Product API but all requests come back as "Error 429 - Too many requests"

Tags: amazon-product-api

I recently got access to the Amazon Product API, and I was trying to experiment with some requests both on my Node.JS environment and on ScratchPad.

But all my requests come back as `Error 429 - Too many requests`. So far, I haven't been able to make any successful requests using the API.

[image]

Has anyone had this issue before? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message when trying to access the API via the python SDK. I figured out that besides *acces_key*, *secret_key*, and *partner_tag* I needed to set *host*, *region*, and *marketplace* to the country-specific values according to https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/common-request-parameters.html#host-and-region.

While this seems obvious in retrospective, the error message 429 "too many requests" does not really hint to fix that.

Comment: Also, I thought simply having a access key and secret key implied I had API access but *it does not!*  It's deactivated on their end unless you have 3 completed sales through your affiliate tags in the last 90 days.  They don't make this clear enough, IMO.